# Can we calculate time taken to execute each step in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, performance-testing

I have a task in which I have to calculate the time taken by each step, for example if we are clicking on a link, how much time is taken to load the page and next step to be executed.
I want fail the test case if time taken is more then say 2 seconds.
I have tried using `protractor-perf` and it gives me the readings below and these don't help, or I am not able to read anything correctly.

```
{ Styles: 0,
  Javascript: 0,
  numAnimationFrames: 4625,
  numFramesSentToScreen: 4625,
  droppedFrameCount: 417,
  meanFrameTime_raf: 18.242160830084256,
  framesPerSec_raf: 54.81806729556069,
  connectEnd: 1524251882749,
  connectStart: 1524251882459,
  domComplete: 1524251916054,
  domContentLoadedEventEnd: 1524251916053,
  domContentLoadedEventStart: 1524251916050,
  domInteractive: 1524251916050,
  domLoading: 1524251883038,
  domainLookupEnd: 1524251882459,
  domainLookupStart: 1524251882459,
  fetchStart: 1524251882458,
  firstPaint: 33600.99983215332,
  loadEventEnd: 1524251916055,
  loadEventStart: 1524251916054,
  navigationStart: 1524251882456,
  redirectEnd: 0,
  redirectStart: 0,
  requestStart: 1524251882749,
  responseEnd: 1524251883592,
  responseStart: 1524251883032,
  secureConnectionStart: 0,
  unloadEventEnd: 0,
  unloadEventStart: 0,
  loadTime: 33597,
  domReadyTime: 4,
  readyStart: 2,
  redirectTime: 0,
  appcacheTime: 1,
  unloadEventTime: 0,
  domainLookupTime: 0,
  connectTime: 290,
  requestTime: 843,
  initDomTreeTime: 32458,
  loadEventTime: 1 }
```

I have also tried using `log-timestamp` and I can print the timestamp to log but cannot get the difference to use it in a variable and fail the test case.
I get the output like this in the log:

```
[2018-04-20T19:19:13.325Z] Start
[2018-04-20T19:19:14.046Z] Step1
[2018-04-20T19:19:47.667Z] Step2
[2018-04-20T19:19:50.304Z] Step3
[2018-04-20T19:19:52.111Z] Step4
[2018-04-20T19:19:57.344Z] Step5
[2018-04-20T19:19:59.029Z] Step6
```

I would really appreciate your help guys, this has wasted a lot my time.

Comment: For the tests to fail at, for example 2 seconds, you can change the time out of the `expectedConditions`: `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#abc')), 2000);`.

Comment: Have you resolved it?